# accessing the phone without a phone number in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My app uses  tel: (someNumber) to dial out however I also need to just launch the phone so the  user can enter a number. Using Swift. Is this possible?

Comment: I found this in my search - urlToUse(urlSent: ("launch://dial")) but this did not work in the app

Comment: It seems that Apple does not want to allow direct access to phone without a number and I have found a similar issue with FaceTime.